# Column l' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause - but it is

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a sql subquery that does the following - it calculates some sums based on a over partition of a column. After that in I want to inner join the table with itself so that I could get the difference between dates.
The problem that it is showing is:

***Column 'tblFinansijskiPodaci.DatumVal' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.***

The problem started when I inserted the date values in the DATEDIFF. When I insert some random date values like '2017/08/25', '2011/08/25' it works fine.

Is maybe my join in the wrong place?

This is my query:

```
SELECT P2.FinID, P2.Firma, P2.BrojDok, P2.DatumVal,P2.Saldo ,P2.SaldoTotal2,
IIF(P2.SaldoTotal2<0,0,IIF(P2.SaldoTotal2<1,(DATEDIFF(DAY,P2.DatumVal, b.DatumVal)),0))
AS NumberOfDays
FROM
   (
     SELECT P1.FinID, P1.Firma,P1.BrojDok,P1.DatumVal,P1.Saldo,P1.SaldoTotal,
     IIF(P1.SaldoTotal<0,0,IIF(P1.SaldoTotal>1,1,0)) AS SaldoTotal1,
     IIF(P1.SaldoTotal<0,0,IIF(P1.SaldoTotal<1,0,1)) AS SaldoTotal2
 FROM 
     (
       SELECT P.FinID,P.Firma,P.BrojDok,P.DatumVal,P.Saldo ,
       SUM(Saldo) OVER (PARTITION BY BrojDok ORDER BY FinID) AS SaldoTotal
   FROM
       (
        SELECT a.FinID,  a.Firma, a.Konto,a.NazivKonta, a.NazFirme, a.BrojDok,
        a.DatumVal,a.Valuta,
        Sum(IIf(a.[Konto] Like '2%',a.[Duguje] -a.[Potrazuje],a.[Potrazuje] -a.[Duguje]))
        AS Saldo
        FROM tblFinansijskiPodaci a WHERE a.Firma = 1 AND a.Konto = 2040
        AND a.Partner = 1137
        GROUP BY a.FinID,a.Firma,a.NazFirme,a.Konto,a.NazivKonta,a.BrojDok,
        a.DatumVal,a.Valuta,a.Duguje,a.Potrazuje
       ) AS P
  GROUP BY FinID,Firma,BrojDok,Saldo,DatumVal
     ) AS P1
 GROUP BY P1.FinID,P1.Firma,P1.BrojDok,P1.DatumVal,P1.Saldo,P1.SaldoTotal
) AS P2 
 INNER JOIN tblFinansijskiPodaci b ON b.BrojDok=P2.BrojDok
 GROUP BY P2.FinID,P2.Firma,P2.BrojDok,P2.Saldo,P2.SaldoTotal,P2.SaldoTotal1,P2.SaldoTotal2,P2.DatumVal
        ORDER BY BrojDok
```

Comment: When I see subqueries nested 4 deep all pulling from the same table it is a huge red flag that something is a bit left of center. It is hard to tell what is really going on here because the formatting is difficult but I suspect this could be greatly simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `b.DatumVal` in your last `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: you are right! I can't believe I didn't saw that. I will accept you answer as soon as possible

Comment: I'm glad I could help you